# binding to value in Dictionary with enum as a key

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dictionary, enums

I'm some application and i would like to bind some textboxes and chekcboxes to value field of Dictionary(Enum, string). Is this possible and how can I do that?

In xaml code I have something like this - it is working for Dictionary with string as a key, but it cannot correctly bind to key with enum

```
<dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Properties[PrimaryAddress],  Mode=TwoWay}" />
<dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Properties[SecondaryAddress],  Mode=TwoWay}" />
<dxe:CheckEdit EditValue="{Binding Properties[UsePrimaryAddress], Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

.. and here is what I have in Enum

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    PrimaryAddress,
    SecondaryAddress,
    UsePrimaryAddress
}
```

In ViewModel dictionary is defined as:

```
public Dictionary<MyEnum, string> Properties
```

I have found solution for combobox with enum values but this does not apply to my case.

Any advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to set appropriate type for indexer's parameter in binding expression.

View model:

```
public enum Property
{
    PrimaryAddress,
    SecondaryAddress,
    UsePrimaryAddress
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Properties = new Dictionary<Property, object>
        {
            { Property.PrimaryAddress, "123" },
            { Property.SecondaryAddress, "456" },
            { Property.UsePrimaryAddress, true }
        };
    }

    public Dictionary<Property, object> Properties { get; private set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Properties[(local:Property)PrimaryAddress]}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Properties[(local:Property)SecondaryAddress]}"/>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Properties[(local:Property)UsePrimaryAddress]}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

For more info, see "[Binding Path Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview#Path_Syntax)".

Comment: Using above binding path I got following error: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''Dictionary`2' (HashCode=56465364)'. BindingExpression:Path=Properties[(mbpt:MyEnum)UsePrimaryAddress]; DataItem='MyUserControlViewModel' (HashCode=21018822); target element is 'CheckEdit' (Name=''); target property is 'EditValue' (type 'Object')

Comment: Uh, never mind. I made some mistake in binding path. Your solution is working now. Thank you :)

Comment: Awesome ! And what if the enum is nested in a class ? :) Thx