# Databinding to entries in a dictionary with enums as keys

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

I'm attempting to databind to an entry in a dictionary where the key is the enum. I've consulted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12690515/102441), but the answer doesn't work for me. Here are the non-boilerplate parts of my code:

---

SomePage.xaml:

```
<!-- Here I try all the ways I can think of. None of them produce any text -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data[0]}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data[EnumValueA]}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data[SomeEnum.EnumValueA]}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data[(local:SomeEnum)EnumValueA]}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Data[(local:SomeEnum)SomeEnum.EnumValueA]}" />
```

SomePage.xaml.cs:

```cs
public SomePage() {
    DataContext = new SomeVM();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

SomeVM.cs:

```cs
public enum SomeEnum {
    EnumValueA, EnumValueB
}
public class SomeVM {
    public Dictionary<SomeEnum, int> Data { get; private set; }
    public SomeVM() {
        Data = new Dictionary<SomeEnum, int> {
            {SomeEnum.EnumValueA, 1337}
        };
    }
}
```

Why does this databinding not work?

Comment: Are you tried `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path = Data[(local:SomeEnum)EnumValueA]}" />`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Adding `Path=` explicitly failed as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. See  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024(v=vs.95).aspx#indexdata

> ## Indexer
>
> Indexers can be used for accessing properties in a path and obtaining
>   items from a list, but with some notable restrictions:
>
> - List item
> - Numeric integer indexers are supported.
> - Beginning in Silverlight 4, string indexers are supported.
> - Only one-dimensional array indexing is supported.
>
> The type being indexed must implement or inherit IList. (List is
>   accepted, because it implements IList. However IList is not
>   accepted.)
>
> Numeric integer indexes are specified by declaring the zero-based
>   index within bracket ([]) characters after the property name; for
>   example, Employees[2].
>
> Property path evaluation first attempts to use integer indexing for a
>   collection. If that indexing is not valid for the collection, then the
>   information within [] is processed as a string. String indexing from a
>   property path generally expects a collection / business object that is
>   a dictionary with string keys. String indexing supports binding to
>   dynamic data objects where the CLR structure of the data source can
>   change, but the string keys represent a data contract that can still
>   be bound to by a client UI.
>
> Validation uses indexers to access items of an attached property's
>   collection as part of its property path usage. The validation
>   structure for the application can declare UI states within templates
>   that are used only when validation errors are raised, and can then
>   reference the active error objects in that context. For example, the
>   following is a property path for a binding that accesses the first
>   item in a Validation.Errors collection; the context of the property
>   path is modified by RelativeSource so that the errors are checked only
>   at run time on the applied template:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
    TemplatedParent}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].Exception.Message }">
```

Comment: Drat. I keep forgetting WPF is not silverlight