# WPF data binding to dictionary with enum key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, enums

I have a solution with a couple of projects. In one project, is my model that has an enum called ModelEnum.

Then in my WPF project I have a ViewModel which has a Dictionary.

And in my ViewModel I have my ValuesDictionary setup as:

```
    private Dictionary<ModelEnum, string> _valuesDictionary = new Dictionary<ModelEnum, string>();

    public Dictionary<ModelEnum, string> ValuesDictionary
    {
        get { return _valuesDictionary; }
        set { _valuesDictionary = value; OnPropertyChanged(_valuesDictionary); }
    }
```

In my XAML I have:

```
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Model.Data;assembly=Model"
...
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ValuesDictionary[(model:ModelEnum)ModelEnum.Enum1].Value}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="90,82,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50"/>
```

The following XAML snippet:

```
(model:ModelEnum)ModelEnum.Enum1
```

is giving me the error "Parameter type mismatch." I'm confused because I thought I was casting this to the Enum type that it was expecting. I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690515/binding-to-value-in-dictionary-with-enum-as-a-key) SO question to try it with no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replace

```
(model:ModelEnum)ModelEnum.Enum1].Value
```

with

```
(model:ModelEnum)Enum1]
```

Then try. I hope it will work.

Comment: I think you mean replace the whole `[(model:ModelEnum)ModelEnum.Enum1].Value` (Note about the **.Value**) with `[(model:ModelEnum)Enum1]`. Otherwise the OP may think the new expression is `[(model:ModelEnum)Enum1].Value` which won't work.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! For some reason the xaml editor is still showing a red squiggly line underneath it, but when I tested it, all was good.

Comment: @Taran: pfff, I spent all afternoon debugging this. Couldn't find a good answer anywhere until I finally found this! Thanx!

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the potential pitfalls with this, I had issues binding without the explicit "Path="

i.e.

```
{Binding ValuesDictionary[(model:ModelEnum)Enum1]}
```

doesn't work, but:

```
{Binding Path=ValuesDictionary[(model:ModelEnum)Enum1]}
```

works as expected, although the designer (or maybe ReSharper) still complains about syntax errors.