# Databinding to Dictionary<Enum, string> using DataTemplate Object as a Key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, enums

Using several other questions such as [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597331/wpf-data-binding-to-dictionary-with-enum-key?noredirect=1&lq=1). I have found how to bind to a `Dictionary<Enum, string>` from xaml, as follows:

```
{Binding Path=Dictionary[ (namespace:EnumModel) EnumValue ]}
```

However, my issue arises once I introduce a `DataTemplate` and try to use the object data property in place of `EnumValue`. I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
{Binding Path=Dictionary[ (namespace:EnumModel) ObjectDataProperty ]}
```

I am using this approach for a dynamic layout which transforms an `Enum` property into a `string` value with more appropriate formatting, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**ANSWER:**

Thanks to Pavel, here's the final product:

XAML:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DictionaryAccessor}">
    <Binding Path="DataContext.Dictionary" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
    <Binding Path="Data.ObjectProperty"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Converter:

```
public class DictionaryAccessor : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var dict = values[0] as Dictionary<EnumModel, string>;
        var key = values[1] as EnumModel?;

        return key != null && dict != null ? dict[key.Value] : null;
    }
}
```

It's important to note that the `Data.` and `DataContext.` tags in the `Binding` fields are essential here. I was unable to access the objects without them.

Comment: Dictionaries are terrible for databinding. I always avoid them like the plague. I've got an implementation of KeyedCollection<K,V> that implements INotifyCollectionChanged that I use instead.

Comment: Could you tell me why Dictionaries are poor for databinding? Also, could you please share some details of your implementation and why it is a better alternative?

Comment: Because all collection-based controls in WPF run against IEnumerables. And Dictionary<K,T> is an IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,V>>.  Since it's a collection of KVPs, you lose out on the benefits of DataTemplates, among other problems. A KeyedCollection<K,V> doesn't wrap your type in another type.  It implements IEnumerable<V>, so you don't have this artificial type interfering with how WPF handles collections, types, and data templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass only a literal value to the indexer in the path.
If you want to dynamically select an item from the dictionary using the value of some property as the key, you can achieve it using MultiBinding.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DictionaryAccessor}">
    <Binding Path="Dictionary" />
    <Binding Path="ObjectDataProperty" />
</MultiBinding>
```

`DictionaryAccessor` is as `IMultiValueConverter` that you must write to access the element. Its Convert method will be similar to this:

```
var dict = values[0] as IDictionary<EnumModel, SomeType>; // Replace SomeType with your real object type.
var key = values[1] as EnumModel?;
return key != null ? dict[key.Value] : null;
```

Comment: Great answer, I had not thought of using `IMultiValueConverter`.