# Binding a Label Content to a Dictionary Value

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I have a Dictionary like:

```
 private static readonly Dictionary<LdType, string[]> 
loadTypeList = new Dictionary<LdType, string[]>()
    {
     { LdType.Force ,new [] { "Force","....","...."  } },
.... etc
      };
```

etc. It's a property that can be bound to.

Then I have a Propertry LoadType of type enum LdType. I use it to index (Key) into the Dictionary and get the first item of the string array to show as a Label.
I tried a lot of things, like:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:MyViewModel.LoadTypeList},
          Path=[LoadType].Value[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The Source part is OK, but the Path does not work, obviously.

Also Path=[LoadType][0] does not.

How would I do this, without a converter?

Comment: Have you seen this discussion: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26597331/wpf-data-binding-to-dictionary-with-enum-key)?? I think `Path=[LoadType]...` cannot work. It has to be something like `Path=LoadTypeList[(ns:LdType)LdType.Force][0]`

Comment: Besides that `Path=[LoadType]...` wont work, *It's a property that can be bound to* is wrong. It would have to be a public property instead of a private field. And `loadTypeList` is not `LoadTypeList`.