# two way binding to value in dictionary

Tags: vb.net, xaml, dictionary

in theory my question is somewhat similar to [binding to value in Dictionary with enum as a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690515/binding-to-value-in-dictionary-with-enum-as-a-key).
The mayor problem is, that i dont know how to make the solution form the linked question two sided

At present I'm at a point where the binding works, but I cant imagine how to make it two-way

here is a, extremly reduced, form of the window code in question

```
''' <summary>
''' Code-behind of window
''' </summary>
Class TestWindow
    'Key=Name Value = Dictionary of ( Date[formated as string] , Time [formated as String])
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))

    Public Property currentTime As String
        Set(value As String)
            If Not dict Is Nothing Then
                dict(me.Name)(Today) = value
            End If
        End Set
        Get
            If dict Is Nothing OrElse Not dict.ContainsKey(Name) OrElse Not dict(me.Name).ContainsKey(Today.ToString("yyyy MM dd")) Then
                Return ""
            Else
                Return dict(me.Name)(Today.ToString("yyyy MM dd"))
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

and the XML is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWindow" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectTimers"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>          
        <Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding currentTime}" MinWidth="100" Margin="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="right"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Try changing the Label to a TextBox, and bind `currentTime` (why the Java naming btw?) to `Text` instead of `Content`.

Comment: regarding the Java thing: Bad habit of university I guess, for them Java is the sole language and so all the conventions in my mind are javafied...
Regarding the propased change: that didn't help. If I modify the value for a project "sample" for daykey "2017 05 08" from "00:02:00" to 00:12:00" the value gets changed in dictionary but does not update on UI

Comment: Well, you need to raise `PropertyChanged` for `currentTime` when you change it. This hasn't anything to do with the dictionary; that's private, the Binding never interacts with it directly.

Comment: I´m no wpf expert but don´t you need a collection that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` like `ObservableCollection` or like [this dictionary](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/)?

Comment: @AlexB. If he were binding to the collection, certainly, but he's binding to a public property that uses a dictionary as an internal store. If that were an `ObservableDictionary`, that wouldn't help, unless he handled its CollectionChanged event and raised PropertyChanged there (which come to think of it, may not be a bad idea).

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes fair point. thanks for clarification.